# How to use map functions?

Tags: f#

So I have many types that have been defined and functions which mapped data into these records/types. Now I need to map the contents of each record/type into a "master" record which will contain everything from previous records based on a key which in this case is State. I am not sure how to go about doing this, but I have my attempt down below, along with more code to provide context. Any suggestions? Please comment if you need more information.

I have types that are defined as so:

```
type StateEdu = 
    { State : string
      Education : int
      Income : float }

type StateFamily =
    { State : string
      PctMoreThan4Children : float
      PctFamilyMorethan3 : float }
```

But now I need to do something LIKE THIS (This did not work when I ran it):

```
let stateall = statemap.Keys

let statedatamap =
 stateall
 |> Seq.map (fun state ->
    state,
    {State = state
     StateEdu = StateEdu.[state]
     StateFamily = StateFamily.[state]
     })
|> Map.ofSeq
```

Comment: why doesn't it work? could you distill it down to a smaller example? that would help identify a good solution.

Comment: skip the csv provider, and use some mock data for example. what is the error message you're getting? Generally just saying this didn't work is not helpful.

Comment: You have no type defined for the last record with item `StateEdu`. and you are missing some other data like `statemap` as well.

Comment: I added the necessary changes, you need your record to take the other records as items. See below the edited answer. You know best about the output so you can edit the record, and index into the map, then index into the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what is your desired output as you're missing both variables and types. Assuming you want a new map/dictionary that contains the key of a state, and then a record which has the both the education state and the family state, one way would be is this: 
(I added the types and fixed some errors)

```
type StateEdu = 
    { State : string
      Education : int
      Income : float }

type StateFamily =
    { State : string
      PctMoreThan4Children : float
      PctFamilyMorethan3 : float }

//I added this new type so this is value of the final map.    
type State2 = 
    { State : string
      StateEdu : StateEdu
      StateFamily : StateFamily }

//Instead providing the csv it's better to minimize the example, so here are the two record lists.      
let stateEdu = 
  [{State = "TX"; Income = 51522.; Education = 0}
   {State = "AL"; Income = 6481.; Education = 1}
   {State = "MO"; Income = 78921.; Education = 1}
   {State = "TN"; Income = 12000.; Education = 4}
   {State = "PA"; Income = 79850.; Education = 2}
   {State = "NY"; Income = 79215.; Education = 1}
   {State = "CA"; Income = 79045.; Education = 2}]

let datafamily = 
  [{State = "TX"; PctMoreThan4Children = 51.52; PctFamilyMorethan3 = 65.0}
   {State = "AL"; PctMoreThan4Children = 64.00; PctFamilyMorethan3 = 51.4}
   {State = "MO"; PctMoreThan4Children = 78.92; PctFamilyMorethan3 = 25.1}
   {State = "TN"; PctMoreThan4Children = 12.00; PctFamilyMorethan3 = 62.1}
   {State = "PA"; PctMoreThan4Children = 8.50; PctFamilyMorethan3 = 41.2}
   {State = "NY"; PctMoreThan4Children = 25.15; PctFamilyMorethan3 = 31.0}
   {State = "CA"; PctMoreThan4Children = 79.5; PctFamilyMorethan3 = 50.5}]


let stateedu =
     stateEdu
     |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.State,x)
     |> Map.ofSeq

let datafam =
     datafamily
     |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.State,x)
     |> Map.ofSeq

//This is one way to quickly extract the keys
let stateall = stateedu |> Map.toSeq |> Seq.map fst  

//We go through all the keys
let statedatamap =
 stateall
 |> Seq.map (fun state ->
    state,
    {State = state //this is the State2type
     StateEdu = stateedu.[state] 
     StateFamily = datafam.[state]
     })
|> Map.ofSeq
```

Output:

> val statedatamap : Map =   map
>       [("AL", {State = "AL";
>                StateEdu = {State = "AL";
>                            Education = 1;
>                            Income = 6481.0;};
>                StateFamily = {State = "AL";
>                               PctMoreThan4Children = 64.0;
>                               PctFamilyMorethan3 = 51.4;};});
>        ("CA", {State = "CA";
>                StateEdu = {State = "CA";
>                            Education = 2;
>                            Income = 79045.0;};
>                StateFamily = {State = "CA";
>                               PctMoreThan4Children = 79.5;
>                               PctFamilyMorethan3 = 50.5;};});
>        ("MO", {State = "MO";
>                StateEdu = {State = "MO";
>                            Education = 1;
>                            Income = 78921.0;};
>                StateFamily = {State = "MO";
>                               PctMoreThan4Children = 78.92;
>                               PctFamilyMorethan3 = 25.1;};});
>        ("NY", {State = "NY";
>                StateEdu = {State = "NY";
>                            Education = 1;
>                            Income = 79215.0;};
>                StateFamily = {State = "NY";
>                               PctMoreThan4Children = 25.15;
>                               PctFamilyMorethan3 = 31.0;};});
>        ("PA", {State = "PA";
>                StateEdu = {State = "PA";
>                            Education = 2;
>                            Income = 79850.0;};
>                StateFamily = {State = "PA";
>                               PctMoreThan4Children = 8.5;
>                               PctFamilyMorethan3 = 41.2;};});
>        ("TN", {State = "TN";
>                StateEdu = {State = "TN";
>                            Education = 4;
>                            Income = 12000.0;};
>                StateFamily = {State = "TN";
>                               PctMoreThan4Children = 12.0;
>                               PctFamilyMorethan3 = 62.1;};});
>        ("TX", {State = "TX";
>                StateEdu = {State = "TX";
>                            Education = 0;
>                            Income = 51522.0;};
>                StateFamily = {State = "TX";
>                               PctMoreThan4Children = 51.52;
>                               PctFamilyMorethan3 = 65.0;};})]

If necessary you can define your output type to include both records as one item. You can always index to the record by `statedu.[state].Education` for example.

Comment: I would make that a different question as this example is already a bit too big. Generally you can index into as many different types as you want. If you do not want to restrict your ouput to a specific record type you can just return a tuple. You might also be indexing into the wrong record or using records with the same fields (so  the compiler can't tell them apart). But you can certainly skip `State2` and just return the raw data (as a tuple for example).

Comment: @JohnLaw if your example is a bit too convoluted you can use [F# Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f)